# Elements of a subset of $S_n$ given its inversion number?

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

Given $ I\subseteq S_n$  subset of permutations that only have $\frac{(n^2-n)}{2}$ inversions. How can I describe the order of the generating subgroup $\langle I \cup (\,1 2)\ \rangle$?

I know that $I$ has n elements, but think that  the permutation $(\,1 2)\in I $ when $ n\geq 2$ so the order of $\langle I \cup (\,1 2)\ \rangle$ is n?